# Inserting SQL Server view result to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Server view `vwSales` which returns all sales from yesterday. I want to dump the result into an actual table (`tblSales`) which needs to be recreated daily.

How to implement it by creating a script and automate the running thru SQL Server Agent?

This is the logic:

- If tblSales exist then delete (for data refresh)

  ```
  Select * 
  from vwSales

  Insert to tblSales (to be recreated from the result of vwSales)
  ```

The job will run once a day before start of business hours.

Comment: Why do you need to "recreate" it daily ? You can do a `delete tblSales` before `insert`

Comment: the tblSales is just a dump table that needs to be recreated daily, and will be the source of some adhoc reports.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the existence of a table

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'tblSales')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Table Exists'
END
```

and you can insert-select values, like this:

```
INSERT INTO destination_table(...)
SELECT ...
FROM source_table
...
```

So, you will need to properly specify the fields in the `insert` clause and the `select` clause and put the insert-select into the if.

Answer (score 1):

This query will check that if the table exists, it will drop it. Assuming that you need to create the table every time as your table/view structure may change, you want to handle this by script.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'tblSales' AND type = 'U')
DROP TABLE tblSales
GO
```

The query will create the table based on data returns by the View and insert the records as well.

```
select * into tblSales from vwSales
```